# JavaScript: Serialize XML to String without line breaks

Tags: javascript, xml, string, serialization

I'm serializing an XML document to String using JavaScript, but I can't get rid of the line breaks.

Simple XML Example:

```
<list>
    <item label='one'/>
    <item label='two'/>
</list>
```

When I use:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
xmlString = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(xml);
```

...the line breaks and indentations are preserved (visible when printing xmlString) but I want the whole XML to look like this:

```
<list><item label='one'/><item label='two'/></list>
```

I tried this:

```
xmlString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

...but I don't find it a reliable and clean solution. It should only affect the XML structure, not the content within the XML elements.

Any idea?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me, just remember that replace will return a new string, so try xmlString = xmlString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

Comment: It might be, that it just looks as if your XML contains these characters. Many tools to print or view an XML prettyfy it automatically...